# Propagate server identity through Weblogic EJB calls

Tags: security, weblogic, ejb

Is there a way to assign an identity to a Weblogic server so that calls from one server to another will propagate the calling server identity?

As an example, I have two servers : ServerA and ServerB. I have a test client that looks up an EJB on ServerA and invokes a method on it. The EJB on ServerA then looks up an EJB on ServerB and invokes a method on it.

When using authentication in the first call, the principal is propagated from ServerA to ServerB so that context.getCallerPrincipal() returns the same on both servers.

Now I would like to call the EJB on ServerA without using authentication, and when the EJB is called on ServerB, it should return ServerA's principal when I invoke context.getCallerPrincipal().

The end result is that I want to be able to specify that ServerA can call EJB methods on ServerB, but ServerX for instance shouldn't be allowed to.

I'm not sure if this is even possible?